# programming for excel with foxpro (or any suggestions)

Tags: excel

I have a macro in excel that works.

```
Sub jim()

Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion.Select    

    Selection.RowHeight = 13
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
```

…etc.

If I open a csv and run this macro it selects the seen data and then later does stuff to it.

So I made a foxpro program to do the same.

When I try to run in foxpro, I get a variable not found error.

---

```
local oExcel, oSheet

oExcel = CreateObject([Excel.Application])
oExcel.Visible = .T.

k:\wellcarestuff\All Data Files\"+ALLTRIM(xlfiles(1,1))

osheet = oexcel.workbooks.open("k:\wellcarestuff\all data files\20131210_CT_TransportationAddresses.csv")    <<<===  it opens and shows the sheet here


Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion.Select  <<<?===   get an error here?
```

Is the var it wants the current osheet?

Answer (score 0):

On the line with the path, it looks like you are missing the beginning quote marks so it things that k:... is a variable.  Should be:

"k:\wellcarestuff\All Data Files\"+ALLTRIM(xlfiles(1,1))

Try that and see if it works.